# How can I add Azure BC2 authentication to the SignalR connection in a Java program?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, signalr

I have a Java program that is not a not a web application that connects to an Azure SignalR hub running in ServerLess mode and listens for events. This program is run on different operating systems including Windows, macOS and Linux. The program uses the ASP.NET Core SignalR Java client.

I would like to add authentication to validate with Azure BC2 using a username and password.

Here is a simple example to connect to SignalR:

```
    /**
     * Example program for SignalR.
     *
     * @param args the program arguments, which consists of the URL for the SignalR
     *             server and the hub name.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.print("\nUsage: ");
            System.out.print(Example.class);
            System.out.println(" signalr_url hubname");
            return;
        }
        try {
            final HttpHubConnectionBuilder builder = HubConnectionBuilder.create(args[0]);
            final HubConnection hubConnection = builder.build();
            final Action1<Object> callback = new Action1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void invoke(Object param1) {
                    System.out.print("Signalr hub connection ID: ");
                    System.out.println(hubConnection.getConnectionId());
                    System.out.println(param1);
                }
            };
            hubConnection.on(args[1], callback, Object.class);
            // start the hub connection and wait until connected
            hubConnection.start().blockingAwait();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have found examples of how to do this with a Java web application or a Java program running on Windows but I need a solution for any OS.